# EventKit crash: "Frozen alarm is of the wrong class: EKPersistentAlarm"

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

We are seeing some crashes from users who try to save a reminder to the EKEventStore.

The crash happens when trying to save the reminder like this

```
try eventStore.save(ekReminder, commit: true)
```

We have wrapped the call into a do-catch and it does not throw an error (that would be handled), but it simply crashes.

We are unable to reproduce this issue on our own devices. Therefore the question is, if anyone knows how this crash can occur, so we can either fix it blindly or at least try to reproduce it. Searching for the error message "Frozen alarm is of the wrong class: EKPersistentAlarm" has not yielded any results.

Comment: Did you figure out what is causing this crash? I'm seeing similar crashes, but can't reproduce them.